# Not receiving order placed notice in Satchmo

Tags: python, django, satchmo

I was wondering if there are any settings I need to do to enable Satchmo sending me an email (to the store config email address) each time an order is placed? I have set up the template:

templates/shop/email/order_placed_notice.html and enabled Send HTML Email in the settings.

The site is sending the order placed and order shipped emails to the customer no problems, but is not sending an email to the store email. I have searched through the Satchmo docs around the settings and couldn't find anything. Should I be changing something to the signals? I have gone through the signals.py, listeners.py and mail.py files and done reading on Django & Satchmo Signals but was reluctant to play around as my programming knowledge isn't too great.

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I managed to find the solution for this. It was a setting under the Satchmo /settings/ page, under the Payment section:

Email Owner? Needs to be ticked.

Feel like a bit of an idiot for missing this, but the reason I skipped over the payment section is that I'm using a custom payment module so didn't think it would apply. I am now using this setting alongside my custom payment module and all is working fine.

Comment: Thanks for following up on your question. Configuring the Satchmo settings isn't the most straight-forward process.